# Masonry layout bug on Safari, using a Wordpress site

Tags: javascript, wordpress, safari, masonry

I'm stumped. I use Masonry on my Wordpress site, and it looks fine on all major browsers except for Safari.

Here is an article link, for example:

[masonry article about apple watch on a wordpress site](http://www.trendzulu.com/2015/06/04/a-new-apple-watch-video-has-surfaced-and-it-was-by-far-the-most-interestingly-nostalgic-video-to-make-it-out-to-the-internet/)

On Safari the div items are all squashed up, and I have no idea why.

- I've deactivated all plugins, made no difference
- I've tried using position:absolute; inside the div item, but then the blocks overlapped
- I've tried vertical-align:top; inside the div item, made no difference

Any help would be appreciate. Really stumped on this one...THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @dcardoso mentioned, your item class with the backface-visibility style is causing the issue. It seems that adding a transform forces safari to correctly render the item.

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

This style: `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` in your .item class is causing the issue in safari.

Comment: Thanks @dcardoso. It helped, but a few of the highchart entries didnt render properly. By adding the -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); code mentioned below it worked fine.